# Passing Object to new activity return null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

This is my intent:

```
Intent intentPay = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PayScreenActivity.class);
                    intentPay.putExtra(PayScreenActivity.CHAVE_COMIDA, idRestaurante);
                    intentPay.putStringArrayListExtra("LISTA_COMIDAS", convertedSelected);
                    intentPay.putExtra("COMIDAS", comidasPedidasObj);
                    startActivity(intentPay);
```

And this is me getting values:

```
public class PayScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String CHAVE_COMIDA = "COMIDA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_screen);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> listaComidas = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("LISTA_COMIDAS");
    ArrayList<Comida> listaFinal = intent.getParcelableExtra("COMIDAS");

}
```

}

[comidasPedidasObj have 3 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoznD.png)

And my error:

[But it comes Null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBnOT.jpg)

Comment: I believe that you already know that debugging on some line did not execute code for that particular line - if so there is some kind of issue, if not try stepping to the next instruction and then check the value on that list. (Also try putting images to your question directly)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, can you share more detail?  what is the `comidasPedidasObj` value?

Comment: Hi, its this "public ArrayList<Comida> comidasPedidasObj = new ArrayList<>();" @javadroid

Comment: I have already stepped to next instruction the value is null. (Its my first post i don't know how to do that, but i will try on next one) @itwasntme

Comment: Sounds like `comidasPedidasObj` is not a `getParcelableExtra`, does it not give you a type check error log in Logcat?

Comment: No, the only error I got its when i try to access my 'listaFinal' its says 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty()' on a null object reference' @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 final Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> listaComidas = 
   intent.getStringArrayListExtra("LISTA_COMIDAS");
 ArrayList<Comida> listaFinal = 
intent.getExtras("COMIDAS");
```

You are passing extras to your intent but u arent extracting those intents data. Try the above code pls.

Comment: Its says Incompatible types.  Required: android.content.Intent   Found: android.os.Bundle

Comment: Add getextra instead of parcelable

Comment: Doesn't work getExtras() cannot be applied to (java.lang.String).